# Fedora Core 6 - upgrade or re-install

Tags: linux, fedora

I am having a look at an old server that is running Fedora Core 6.

Is it possible to upgrade it to the latest Fedora?  Should we do that?

I see instructions going from [6 to 7](http://benperove.com/howto/upgrade-fc6-to-f7/), 7 to 8, etc... but it seems like the pain of going that route will be similar to just installing from scratch and re-configuring things from backups etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-install would be better option. The latest fedora is fedora 11 and lot of things would have changed from Fedora 6 to Fedora 11 including

1. Location of some config files
2. Format of config files
3. Default set of tools which get installed with Fedora

Answer (score 3):

**You should definitely install it from scratch.**

Even if you perform a step-by-step update, you most likely get problems with even between the "small" update steps.

Because of that I would even think about a reinstall if it were just an upgrade from Fedora 10 to Fedora 11, but going from 6 to 11, it's a definite **yes**. You'll save time.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with DR in that it's very easy to perform an upgrade from one Fedora version to the next with recent versions - see [this link.](http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/358/upgrading-to-fedora-11-from-fedora-10/)

Going from 6 to 11 is a different matter, though; I agree with the other posts that the changes are significant enough that you'd be much better off doing a reinstall.

Comment: Yes, the upgrade process itself is very easy. But I've never had a Fedora update after which I hadn't have to fix all kinds of problems. Most times it was related to configuration file problems.