# Fedora Core 6 - how to determine packages with security risks?

Tags: linux, fedora

Relating to my question on [upgrading a Fedora Core 6 machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/41490/fedora-core-6-upgrade-or-re-install), in the interim, before the upgrade is completed (which may take some time, given its not my machine, etc etc), are there any Fedora utils for identifying packages with security risks, like the Gentoo glsa-check command?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend **upgrading** ... even if there were other people looking at the packages, it probably would not:

1. Make it to the distro's update repo
2. Make it upstream, because it is a super-old release

No one cares. If you are using FC6 for a specific package, build a little **directory jail/chroot** with the distro libs in there and make the executable think you are using FC6.

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning to update FC6 to a newer version or just patch it?   FC6 is no longer actively supported.

Comment: probably end up just updating

Answer (score 0):

If something like that existed, I would still be using F8.